# count the number of occurences of each word in the text

Tags: python, loops, dictionary

I am trying to count the number of  count of occurrence of each word in a text,
I have below code but it seems that it is not jumping to  the else part of my loop

```py
text = "Joy is joy but joy is not finding a solution"
x= {}
for mot in text.lower().split():
  if x.get(mot) not in x.keys():
    print(mot)
    x[mot] = 1
    print(x[mot])
  else :
    print("the word is" + mot)
    x[mot] = (x[mot]+1)
    print((x[mot]))
  print(x)

x
```

Any help appreciated to resolve it with an if loop

Comment: Please edit your code to be readable, as it is it's incomprehensible.

Answer (score 1):

You are checking wrong condition in if statement, when you call get method and pass it a key it returns its value, which means you are checking for value of that key in the keys of that dictionary.
Its working solution could be:

```
text = "Joy is joy but joy is not finding a solution" 
x= {}
for mot in text.lower().split(): 
    if mot not in x.keys(): 
        x[mot] = 1 
    else:
        x[mot] += 1

print(x)
```